# EC2 - S3 connectivity

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is it possible to use S3 APIs from an EC2 instance that does not have a elastic / public IP? Alternatively, is it possible to whitelist the connection with S3?

We intend to use the APIs to read/write objects from a few buckets on S3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this:

> **Q: Do I need one Elastic IP address for every instance that I have running?**
>
> No. You do not need an Elastic IP address for all your instances. By default, every instance comes with a private IP address and an internet routable public IP address. The private address is associated exclusively with the instance and is only returned to Amazon EC2 when the instance is stopped or terminated. The public address is associated exclusively with the instance until it is stopped, terminated or replaced with an Elastic IP address. These IP addresses should be adequate for many applications where you do not need a long lived internet routable end point. Compute clusters, web crawling, and backend services are all examples of applications that typically do not require Elastic IP addresses.

It looks like you have a public IP even if you don't have an elastic IP, it'll just go away when you stop your instance (and can't be given to another box like elastic IPs can).

So yeah, you should be able to access S3 from any running EC2 instance.

As for whitelisting, I think it depends on how you're doing it? If you're using security groups, all outbound traffic is allowed by default and I don't think you can change that unless you're using VPC. If you're using an internal firewall you'll have to find the S3 IP ranges somewhere on the AWS forums.

Answer (score 0):

You can whitelist and blacklist users and instances using `S3 Bucket Policies` or `IAM Policies` or both.

**S3 Bucket Policies**

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucketPolicies.html

**IAM Policies**

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingIAMPolicies.html